# Can't see custom object types in Webtop but I can in DA

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, webtop

When I try to create a new document in webtop 6.5 sp3 I do not see my cutom object types that I created and installed using composer.

I can however see my custom types in DA and I can create documents with those custom types in DA.

I can also see them in da in the "types" node.

I tried clearing tomcat cache under catalina and documentum cache under c:/documentum/cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured this out. The problem is due to the language. I realized it after noticing da is in english and webtop is in FR.

Here is what I did to fix to the problem.

Enabled french data dictionary in data_dictionary.ini. under documentum/dba/config
Modified data_dictionary_fr under product/6.5/bin to LOCALE = en
Ran the script:
dmbasic -f dd_populate.ebs -e Entry_Point --    D:\Documentum\dba\config\\data_dictionary.ini
Ran the dictionary job again
restarted app server

and now I can see my types.

I'm not sure why this wasn't working ootb though and if all these manipulations were necessary.

Anyway thanks all for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things you could try.

1) Run the Data Dictionary Publishing Job

2) Make sure you are logging in to both Webtop and DA with the same user

I haven't looked at Composer in a while, but I don't recall seeing anything about permissions in there.  I'll have a look and get back to this.

**EDIT**

So I looked in Composer and didn't see anything except the Constraints section.  I've never used this section but if you have anything listed here, please inform us.